# python2.7 how to return a datatype of Double to satisfy element in the WSDL?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xsd, wsdl, double

The element in the WSDL :

`<element name="matchPercentage" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>`

Element in SOAP Response from python2.7 django app:

```
<matchPercentage xsi:type="ns1:float">52.4017467249</matchPercentage>
```

How can I have python2.7  return a double datatype to satisfy the WSDL?

I know by default python does not have a builtin double datatype... is there a way to build one? Or a package I could install?

Looking for any ideas on how to satisfy the WSDL element with type = double.

**Update:**

Also I should mention that the type assign to the xml element in the response is dynamic based on what type the value is in python.  In this case the value is a float datatype in python... so type float is assign to the xml element in the response.

**The Error** (when rendering the xml response):
*Cannot assign object of type System.Single to an object of type System.Double*

**note:** System.Single = Represents a single-precision floating-point number.

Comment: Any SOAP library you are using should map [XML Schema double](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double) to [Python float](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error) since both use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic. I don't really understand your question. What problem are you facing or trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan -

There is a value in the xml response of type float.  But the WSDL says that value needs to be a double. 

So an error is thrown when rendering the xml response:
_Cannot assign object of type System.Single to an object of type System.Double_

Comment: That looks like a .NET error message. Is the SOAP server in Python and the client in .NET? You should try to post some SOAP request/response samples to better explain the flow and what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan -

Yes the SOAP server is python2.7 (django) and the client certainly could be .NET (based on the error message) however it is a vendor's application that is closed source to me at the moment.

I can successfully send a soap request to the python SOAP server(using postman)... see the soap response that is sent back in the logs... and then when the vendor's client app tries to render the soap response... boom the error appears.

Comment: You could try to remove the type attribute from `<matchPercentage xsi:type="ns1:float">52.4017467249</matchPercentage>` and return only `<matchPercentage>52.4017467249</matchPercentage>` to see if that changes anything, but from the looks of it this seems like a client problem which I'm not sure you can solve on the server. The client proxy should expect a double precision floating point because that's what the WSDL says, and handle it as such. Either the client proxy is broken in some way or something downstream of the proxy is broken and tries to assign `System.Double` to `System.Single`

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan -

No luck removing the attribute either.